# Как добавить текст в конец файла в Java?

Tags: java

Есть текстовый файл, в котором уже хранится какая-то информация.

Как дописать в файл данные, если метод `write` класса `FileWritter` затирает старые данные и пишет новые?

Comment: Ключевое слово - append. Посмотрите его в документации на средства, которыми вы открываете/пишете файл.

Comment: `try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("E://Count.txt"))
         {
            
             String text = "some text";
            
             writer.append(text);
         }
        ...` такой код затирает файл

Comment: Открываете документацию на FileWriter, ищете в ней слово append... PROFIT!

Comment: append(char c ) Appends the specified character to this writer. Т.е. это работает так: мы уже записали что-то в файл , и потом в  конец добавили сhar С например :  
`FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("E://Count.txt")
writer.write("some text");
writer.append("X");`

будет some textX, а мне нужно что бы в существующий файл дописывало

Comment: За что вопрос закрыли-то?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Метод 1:

Один из вариантов - использовать [метод write класса Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20byte[],%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "/home/user/Desktop/project/src/myfile.txt";
        String text = "Hello world!\n";

        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get(filePath), text.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Метод 2:

С помощью [FileWriter, созданного соответствующим конструктором](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean))

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String filePath = "/home/user/Desktop/project/src/myfile.txt";
        String text = "Hello world!\n";

        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
            BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            bufferWriter.write(text);
            bufferWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cпасибо! Не пойму ток что означает символ '\n'?

Comment: @ketchyn, это переход на новую строку. Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

```
public FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append) throws IOException
```

Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name **with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written**.
Parameters:
`fileName` - String The system-dependent filename.
`append` - boolean **if true, then data will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning**.
Не то?