# Абзац между строками

Tags: java, строки, arraylist

Есть часть кода, которая добавляет каждый элемент коллекции в текстовый файл, но нужно, чтобы каждый элемент был с новой строки, как это сделать?

```
String prev_text = "";
for (ToyBlocks toyblocks : blocks){ 
    String text = prev_text+"Назва товара: "+toyblocks.name+ ", кол-во кубиков в наборе: " + toyblocks.amount + ", цена: "+toyblocks.uah + "дол." +toyblocks.kopeck+"центов"+"\n";
    prev_text = text;
    String fileName = "G://Результати введения и сортировки данних.txt";
    FileWorker.write(fileName, text);
}
```

код FileWorker:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class FileWorker {
public static void write(String fileName, String text) {
File file = new File(fileName);
try {
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());

    try {
        out.print(text);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
}
```

Comment: хотя бы скажите, что не так?

Comment: А кто такой `FileWorker`? И что у него внутри? `\n` не работает?

Comment: да не работает **\n**

Comment: надо через String Builder?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, или не  в этом дело?

Comment: Он тут не причем...а если вместо `print` писать `println`? должно добавить.... точнее лучше сделать дополнительный аргумент, который если `true` то будет писать `println`, а по умолчанию `print`...... также  помимо этого есть куча других способов дописать в файл. вот один из них http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/463837/191482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Алексей Шиманский, Вы уж извините мое невежество, но у меня ничего не выходит. Весь день что-то читаю, перечитываю и ничего не выходит.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class FileWorker {
public static void write(String fileName, String text) { // параметри путь и текст

try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName, false); // создаем райтер  с параметрами путь и значаение false, означающее. что файл будет перезаписываться
        BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer); // передаем потоку записи райтер?
        bufferWriter.write(text); // записываем текст 
        bufferWriter.write("\n"); // переход на новую строку
        bufferWriter.close();// закрываем поток
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    }
    }
```

Я понимаю, что уже Вас задолбал. Видимо тема данная на самостоятельное обучение оказалась слишком запутанной для меня

Comment: задалбливают те, кто ничего не делает и хочет чтоб за них все делали)) это не ваш случай) ..... Ну в итоге это ответ?)) лучше переход на новую строку сделать так: `bufferWriter.newLine();` тогда скорее всего в юниксовых будет это заменено на `\n` а на виндовсах на `\r\n` ... наверное))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, искренне Вам признателен за то, что работаете со мной. Но проблема не исчезла(

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, даже не догадываюсь в чем проблема

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, почитал в интернете  о методе newLine(), который был Вами предложен, вроде все корректно написано, а не работатет и все(

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что добавление происходит в цикле, в том числе создание потока и его закрытие.... я б лично еще бы метод определил бы, который на вход принимал бы лист строк и в цикле добавлял бы их, а открывал и закрывал поток бы только один раз........ вот пример: http://ideone.com/XiwsQ9   вполне рабочий .... где метод `write` конечно же должен быть в классе `FileWorker`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо буду разбираться. Но пожалуй завтра. голова будет свежее. Если что получится, сразу Вам сообщу)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Вы били прави. Единственное что, так хотел спросить что делает оператор finally в try/catch

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, и что такое throws IOExeption, мне подсказал его прописать компилятор

Comment: @MuscledBoy я вам настоятельно рекомендую для начала изучить основы)) А потом что-то делать... Тогда половина вопросов сами отпадут..... конкретно про finally и IOException [Исключения](http://www.quizful.net/post/java-exceptions)

Comment: понял, больше вопросов нету)