# FileOutputStream запись в файл

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

При записи текста каждый раз создается новый файл "buterbrod.txt" . Возможно ли как-то сделать, чтобы он не создавал новый , а просто дописывал полученные данные?

```
Path path = Paths.get("buterbrod.txt");

    if (Files.exists(path)) {
        System.out.println("файл есть");{
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("buterbrod.txt"));
            System.setOut(out);
        }

    }

    if (Files.notExists(path)) {
        System.out.print("Файла нет");
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("buterbrod.txt"));
        System.setOut(out);
    }
```

Comment: А нет ли другого конструктора  у `FileOutputStream`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463771/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в конструктор `true` – `new FileOutputStream("buterbrod.txt", true)`

У `FileOutputStream` есть перегрузка конструктора с параметром `append`:

[public FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String,%20boolean))