# Перезаписывает файл

Tags: java, list, filewriter

```
private static void writeFile(List<List<Integer>> currentResult, String outputFilePath){
        Path path = Paths.get(outputFilePath);
        while (true){
            try {
                for (List<Integer> lines : currentResult){
                    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                        for (Integer s : lines){
                            writer.write(s + " ");
                        }
                        writer.newLine();
                    }
                }
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                new File(outputFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

почему в файл записывает только элементы последнего листа? я так понимаю затирает, но не понимаю из-за чего.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить текст в конец файла в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463771/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый раз когда вы делаете так

```
BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(...
```

файл будет записываться заново. Конечно у вас остается только последняя запись.
Вынесите создание райтера из цикла.